# manage an onBlur event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set up an onBlur event for an input element that validates the value and, if invalid, "cancels" the blur and refocusses(or focus never loss) the current input.

i have this peace of code already

```
document.getElementById('my_input_id1').onblur = function() {
          var self = this;
          setTimeout(function() { self.focus(); }, 10);
        }
```

Suppose my next focused element is'my_input_id2' which also has an "onblur" event.as focus is already moved to 'my_input_id2'.When i set focus back to 'my_input_id1' the second elment 'my_input_id2' "onblur event is fried.I want to cancel onblur event of second element.i have many other element with "onlur" for Validation.

Can i stop elemnt not to lost focus?
Is there another function that can do it without lost focus??
Should i use some other function that does not lose focus??

Is there another way to get out of this problem??

Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about what you exactly want to do. Your question is bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 $('#my_input_id1').on('blur',function(){
     if(SOME CONDITION){
         setTimeout(function(){
             $('#my_input_id1').focus();
         },100);
         return false;
     }
 });
```

Comment: now #my_input_id2 onblur will fire which is next element??How to control that??

Comment: i have already same as mentioned in question...but having problem with lost focus

Comment: can you share a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

This is quite straight forward to do with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('id1').onblur = function(e) {
         if(this.value.length == 0) {
             this.focus();
             e.preventDefault();
             return false;
         }
}
```

Essentially just refocusing the element based on a criteria, of course this can be anything you want it to be.

and here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m4cZ2/1/

Comment: this.focus() mean that second elemnt onblur will fire??how to stop that becous after onblur focus has moved to second elment??

Comment: I've updated to prevent the default event happening.

Comment: will focus is lost or second elment onblur is called or not??

Comment: Thanks a lot dear....i will check it in my project and will tell you..i think it will work for me ..thanks a lot

Comment: its not working at all dear...can you suggest me another one??